# Which is the key that is used to check a checkbox from keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Windows 7 PC. Mouse in it is not working now, so the only thing I got to operate is the keyboard.

But I got a problem now. I tried to install a software and when I reached the Licence Agreement page, I had to check a checkbox. I pressed Enter key, but it is supposed  to work only for buttons.

So which is the button in the keyboard to check(or mark) the checkbox ?

Comment: @Xavierjazz Are you sure ?

Comment: Not at all. The answers below look so much better.

Comment: Most of the Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts are documented here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the checkbox gets focused, you can use the **Space** key.

Answer (score 6):

After selecting the checkbox using <kbd>Tab</kbd> just use the <kbd>Space</kbd> to *select* or *deselect*.